# Оптимальное обновление записей таблицы БД

Tags: php, mysql

такая ситуация, в базе данных есть таблица, которая состоит из колонок "**OperationID**" и "**Operation_Sum**". Есть скрипт, который находится в кроне, каждый час изменяет значение колонки "**Operation_Sum**", прибавляя к текущему значению рассчитанный коэффициент.

Я делаю так, выгребаю все записи из таблицы, прохожу каждую запись, беру из нее текущее значение "**Operation_Sum**" прибавляю к нему коэффициент и UPDATEом обновляю запись в базе. Получается,если в таблице будет миллион записей, то в цикле миллион раз произойдет обращение к база данных. Это нормально для php? Или можно как-то пачкой обновить строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все делается одним простым запросом? который сразу обновит все записи в таблице без необходимости их предварительного чтения

```
UPDATE mytable SET
  operation_sum = operation_sum + :my_coef;
```

Причем если для расчета коэффициента используются только данные из БД и данные, доступные в MySQL сервере, то PHP и cron тут не нужен. Достаточно встроенных EVENTS

Comment: *PHP и cron тут не нужен. Достаточно встроенных EVENTS* Это при условии, что "рассчитанный коэффициент" может быть рассчитан на MySQL-сервере.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за уточнение

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо, дело в том, что для каждой записи коэффициент разные, но иногда бывает и одинаковый, он не в базе храниться, а рассчитывается согласно определенному алгоритму. Можно в запрос, который вы написали передать к примеру массив с новыми значениями и накатить их на строки таблицы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Может в моём случае проще дропать таблицу и как-то с помощью INSERTа заливать туда все строки одним запросом? Так вообще можно? Или это совсем не комильфо?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, или ещё вариант пришел в голову, может в цикле не лепить строки в базу, а формировать строку запроса? А потом, после цикла сделать запрос к бд, только вот строка будет по идее огромнейшая, это сильно напряжет сервер?

Comment: @alexeyromashev я не сказал, что коэффициент должен храниться в базе. Я говорил, что он может рассчитываться на основании базы. Алгоритм секретный? Удалять все записи а потом заливать это ничем не отличается от того, что у вас сейчас, только еще хуже

Comment: Опишите алгоритм вычисления коэффициента (отредактировав вопрос), а мы подумаем, что с ним можно сделать

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, я вот что нашел, попробую пока так сделать, ещё раз всем спасибо) https://incode.pro/mysql/obnovlenie-neskolkih-zapisej-odnim-zaprosom-v-mysql.html

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, может будет интересно, сделал как вы сказали, мой вариант не подошел. Слишком долго запрос выполнялся, вываливалась из-за этого ошибка. Добавл колонку с коэффициентом в таблицу, она рассчитывается при добавлении новых записей. И запрос получился вот такой : $query = "UPDATE ar_purchases SET accumulation=accumulation+profit";

Comment: @alexeyromashev Если коэффициент не меняется для записи и для каждой записи разный, то это лучшее решение

Comment: @alexeyromashev И я еще раз хочу отметить, что вам для этого не нужны ни PHP, ни cron

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да, добавил все это дело в события, в phpMyAdmin, ещё раз спасибо)